# Perl Regx match a variable with another variable containting *

Tags: regex, perl

```
$define_file_name = "class*";
$file_name="classA1";

if($file_name =~ m/^($define_file_name)$/)
{
   print " File Name Regex matched \n"
}
```

How to match regex  of perl a variable with another variable containing '*' ?

Comment: Do you mean that the `*` should be considered a wild-card?  (Otherwise it just doesn't match.)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob).

Comment: @zdim yes , I want to do matching considering asterisk (*) as a wild-card.

Answer (score 1):

That regex will become:

```
/^class*$/
```

Which means: the string should begin with the literal characters `clas`, followed by `s` repeated 0 or more times (which is what `*` quantifier means in PCRE). So it would match strings like

```
clas
class
classsssss, etc
```

But it would not match wildcards, like

```
classA1
```

For that you need to use the wildcard character: `.`. And your regex becomes:

```
/^class.*$/
```

In other words just add a literal period `.` before your quantifier `*`.

You may also be interested in using [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob). For example:

```
for (<files/class*>) {   # <...> is shorthand for glob "..."
    # now $_ will list the files in folder "files" that begin with "class"
```

You can also put it into an array:

```
my @files = glob "class*";
```

Do note that this requires you to have the actual files in place, and readable by your process with the right path.